# C++: Transpose of Matrix, using SINGLE DIMENSION dynamic array to save elements

Tags: c++

Dear Friends I am having problem to transpose a matrix. The transposed matrix has elements that are undefined. Not sure what is wrong. Thank you for your time!

entries[i] is the dynamic array storing the elements in the matrix. Elements are stored row by row, from left to right. i.e. in a 3X3 matrix, entries[2] is 3rd element on the 1st row, entries[3] is 1st element on the 2nd row

n is the number of rows of matrix

m is the number of columns of matrix

```
Matrix Matrix::Transpose() const {
    double* temp;
    temp = new double[n * m];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            temp[(j - 1) * m + i - 1] = entries[(i - 1) * m + j - 1];
    }
    Matrix Result(m, n, temp);
    delete temp;
    return Result;
}
```

When the original matrix is a square, all elements of the transposed matrix are defined. When the original matrix is 1x3, then the resulting transposed 3x1 matrix has undefined elements for the 2nd and 3rd elements. I.e. (1 1 3) after transposed returns (1 -3452346326236 -12351251515)

The Matrix Print out function is below. The error likely comes from here too.

```
void Matrix::Print() const
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            cout << setw(13) << entries[(i - 1) * m + j - 1];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which elements are undefined?

Comment: When the original matrix is a square, all elements are defined. When the original matrix is 1x3, then the resulting 3x1 matrix has undefined elements for the 2nd and 3rd elements EG (1 1 3) after transposed returns (1 -3452346326236 -12351251515)

Comment: So the undefined elements are where the new rows exceed the old rows? (Or perhaps new columns exceed the old columns?) As if you reversed the limits somewhere?

Comment: I just included the Matrix PRINT function. The error definitely stems from this.

Comment: a 3x1 matrix converts to a 1x3 just fine. THe problem lies in a 1x3 matrix conversion to 3x1. There is something incredibly wrong with my function. 4x2 and 2x4 Matrix fail to Transpose correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the matrix is not square, the line

```
temp[(j - 1) * m + i - 1] = entries[(i - 1) * m + j - 1];
```

is not right. It needs to be:

```
temp[(j - 1) * n + i - 1] = entries[(i - 1) * m + j - 1];
//            ^^ needs to be n, not m.
```

Think of the 2D analogue. You want to use:

```
temp[j][i] = entries[i][j];
```

`entries` is a `n x m` matrix. For it, the 2D indices `[i][j]` are translated as `[i*m + j]` for the 1D index.

`temp` is a `m x n` matrix. For it, the 2D indices `[j][i]` are translated as `[j*n + i]` for the 1D index.

#### Suggestion for improved readability

Instead of `n` and `m`, use `num_rows`, and `num_columns`. You will find your code a lot more readable.